# Text to Matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nlp, data-preprocessing

How can i convert text to matrix just like python devs do using tensor flow text Preprocessing for converting text to matrix.

Even tried 'natural', 'danof' and 'tensorflow' for any utility which can do this but still cant find it.

How its done in python (tfidf)
Source: [text_to_matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer)

```
def texts_to_matrix(self, texts, mode='binary'):
    """Convert a list of texts to a Numpy matrix.
    # Arguments
        texts: list of strings.
        mode: one of "binary", "count", "tfidf", "freq".
    # Returns
        A Numpy matrix.
    """
    sequences = self.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    return self.sequences_to_matrix(sequences, mode=mode)

def sequences_to_matrix(self, sequences, mode='binary'):
    """Converts a list of sequences into a Numpy matrix.
    # Arguments
        sequences: list of sequences
            (a sequence is a list of integer word indices).
        mode: one of "binary", "count", "tfidf", "freq"
    # Returns
        A Numpy matrix.
    # Raises
        ValueError: In case of invalid `mode` argument,
            or if the Tokenizer requires to be fit to sample data.
    """
    if not self.num_words:
        if self.word_index:
            num_words = len(self.word_index) + 1
        else:
            raise ValueError('Specify a dimension (`num_words` argument), '
                             'or fit on some text data first.')
    else:
        num_words = self.num_words

    if mode == 'tfidf' and not self.document_count:
        raise ValueError('Fit the Tokenizer on some data '
                         'before using tfidf mode.')

    x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words))
    for i, seq in enumerate(sequences):
        if not seq:
            continue
        counts = defaultdict(int)
        for j in seq:
            if j >= num_words:
                continue
            counts[j] += 1
        for j, c in list(counts.items()):
            if mode == 'count':
                x[i][j] = c
            elif mode == 'freq':
                x[i][j] = c / len(seq)
            elif mode == 'binary':
                x[i][j] = 1
            elif mode == 'tfidf':
                # Use weighting scheme 2 in
                # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf
                tf = 1 + np.log(c)
                idf = np.log(1 + self.document_count /
                             (1 + self.index_docs.get(j, 0)))
                x[i][j] = tf * idf
            else:
                raise ValueError('Unknown vectorization mode:', mode)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

[WinkNLP](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) has a [BM25 Vectorizer](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/bm25-vectorizer.html), which can convert text to matrix. An example can be viewed at [Runkit](https://runkit.com/winkjs-org/5fe5908307f320001b73ab33).